# Can you create a page specific anchor tag with docusign(Java)?

Tags: java, docusignapi

Is it possible to **create an anchor tag** that ignores a page? `I.E` place that tag on all page except the last page.

Note: I am using `docusign` with java. I cant create unique anchor text for the tags because I don't generate the `pdf` myself I just receive it as a byte array from a parameter.

This is my first question ever on stackoverflow I am sorry if I made any mistakes in asking the questions, If I did please point them out so I can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the platform does not have an option to apply anchor tags to specific pages, however you can configure things such that if a given anchor is not found anywhere to ignore that anchor.

The `anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent` property when set to `true` will make it so no error is returned if you try to match to an anchor that is not found anywhere in the document, so you might be able to use this based on your use-case.

```
anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent:  True or false setting. If true, this tab is ignored if anchorString is not found in the document.
```

[Reference](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Sign%20Here%20Tab.htm?Highlight=anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but the one I was looking for. Yea I know about the anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent setting but it will not be of any use in my current case. Thank you for the help.